# angular-google-maps not rendered fully until browser resized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-google-maps

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="{latitude: 43.100187, longitude: -77.6329959}" 
                    zoom='8'>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

[image]

I loaded all the files using bower and added the dependency to my main module.

```
angular
  .module('main',['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'datatables', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
  .config(config);
```

Map did not render properly until the browser is resized. Is this a bug or is there something wrong with my usage?

Comment: Can you create a demo?

Comment: Try to give a fixed size to the Google Maps' canvas and see if this solves the issue..

Comment: there are classes of the inner html of directive that must have dimension set. You haven't provided any css. Create demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

Setting center and zoom along with `style` attribute on `ui-gmap-google-map` tag should help.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <ui-gmap-markers></ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```